# How to properly display script shell command output

Tags: ansi-term, term

I wish to be able to open current shell output in emacs, for that I use `script` command that logs all the output into file `typescript`. The problem is that it consist also with terminal codes for colors and other necessary stuff, which is not parsed by emacs. I found function `display-ansi-colors` and it displays part of term sequences correctly, but a lot of them still undecoded. I using "xterm-256color" terminal. Is there a way to decode all term sequences correctly in emacs buffer?

Comment: Can you provide a recipe for demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Also, is https://stackoverflow.com/q/22083177 relevant to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

What I've done is inside the shell that `script` starts I `export TERM=dumb` and then after I'm done I exit the shell and clear out any remaining ANSI sequences in the `typescript` file using [ansifilter](http://www.andre-simon.de/doku/ansifilter/en/ansifilter.php) --plain